# Characterize R0-space by convergent filters

Tags: general-topology, filters

I want to prove the equivalence of the two following characterizations of R0-spaces. One comes from my textbook (with filters), the other one is taken from wikipedia. First, I will introduce the definitions I use:

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and for $x \in X$ let $\dot{x}$ denote the principal filter at $x$. Furthermore let $\mathcal{F}(X)$ denote the set of all filters on $X$. A filter $\varphi \in \mathcal{F}(X)$ is said to converge to $x \in X$, symbolically denoted as ($\varphi \to x$), if $\varphi \supseteq \dot{x} \cap \tau$.

I want two show the equivalence of

1. $ \forall \varphi \in \mathcal{F}(X), x,y \in X \,:\, \varphi \to x \land \dot{y} \supseteq  \varphi \implies \varphi \to y,
   $

i.e. every convergent filter $\varphi \to x$ which is contained in a principal filter $\dot{y}$, converges to the point $y$ generating the principal filter and

2. every two points  $x,y \in X$ which are topologically distinguishable, are separable.

Here is my suggestion for (2)$\implies$(1):

Let $\varphi \in \mathcal{F}(X)$, $x,y \in X$ with $\varphi \to x$ and $\dot{y} \supseteq \varphi$ and suppose for the sake of a contradiction $\varphi \not\to y$. Then there exists $O_y \in \tau$ with $y \in O_y$ but $x \not\in O_y$. This means that $x$ and $y$ are topologically distinguishable and (2) gives an open set $O_x \in \tau$ such that $x \in O_x$ but $y \not\in O_x$. This contradicts $\dot{y} \supseteq \varphi$ since $O_x \in \varphi$ while $O_x \not\in \dot{y}$.

**Did I make any mistakes so far? How would I prove (1)$\implies$(2)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, but otherwise your argument is fine: you mean that $x\in O_x$ byt $y\notin O_x$, not that $x\in O_x$ but $y\notin O_y$.

For the other implication suppose that $x,y\in X$ are topologically distinguishable; without loss of generality there is a $U_x\in\dot x\cap\tau$ such that $y\notin U_x$. Suppose that there is no $V\in\dot y\cap\tau$ such that $x\notin V$; then $\dot y\cap\tau\subseteq\dot x$, so $\dot x\supseteq\dot y\to y$, so $\dot y\to x$ by (1). Do you see the contradiction?

Comment: Thank you for spotting the typo and your answer. I think the contradiction is as follows: $\dot{y} \to x$ implies $\dot{x} \cap \tau \subseteq \dot{y}$. This means that in particular $U_x \in \dot{y}$. This is only possible if $y \in U_x$. Which contradicts the chosen $U_x$.

Comment: @el_tenedor: You're welcome. Yes, that's right.